# Oracle 11gR2 installation in Windows 8

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am facing the below issue while trying to install Oracle 11gR2 on windows 8.
Please help me resolving the issue
After this prompt the installer automatically closes down.
I am New to Oracle, i tried looking into multiple forums but no luck.
[image]

Comment: Click on "Details" to see what's wrong. Then try to fix that.

Comment: The software and hardware requirements are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/reqs)

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you two things:

1. Your Java version could not meet requirements. Download the database file which includes Java.
2. Set "compatibility mode" to Windows 7 on setup.exe file.

Comment: The installer includes the correct Java runtime to run itself and it installs the correct Java runtime to be used by the database. So 1. can't be the issue.